# Direct3D strange crash

Tags: c++, sprite, draw, direct3d

I have Direct3D rendering library compiled with VS2008. The another application (built with VS2008) uses my library and everything works fine.

Recently, parent application was moved to VS2010 but my library is still being built under VS2008. And still everything works fine BUT one call on only ONE sprite.

D3DXSprite->Draw method crashes in D3DX9_43.dll in D3DXCore::CSprite::Draw() method. And it occurs only when I'm trying to draw a specific element from texture.

I've also tried to rebuild my library under VS2010, but no success. Crash still occurs.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be want you want to hear, but all I can suggest for debugging something like this is the liberal use of break points and special debugging if-statements.

Place a try-catch statement around the render function that is failing and place a breakpoint in the catch block.

You may need to add some counters and debugging variables so that you can monitor the size/cont of your data structures vs. what your rendering code actually processed.

If you still don't have any hints, it's time to temporarily fork your code (copy it) and simplify. Start ripping out chunks of code to see if it still fails. Eventually you'll narrow it down.

Good luck.

Comment: I'd also consider enabling appverifier on your application - it's possible that D3D is a victim of some other error that happened earlier on.

Comment: Well, the problem has been solved. Actually, it wasn't pretty much D3D problem. I've pointed to invalid texture and therefore Draw() failed. A little more patience while debugging helped ^_^ Thanks!